# Showing the following sequence is monotone decreasing

Tags: sequences-and-series, functions

Let $T$ be fixed and define the functions 
$$a_k(t) = \frac{e^{\mu_k (T-t)} - e^{-\mu_k(T-t)}}{e^{\mu_k T}- e^{-\mu_k T}}$$
for $t \in [0,T]$.

Given that $\mu_k$ is a monotonically increasing sequence of real numbers, how do I show that $a_k$ is monotonic decreasing in $k$ (for fixed $t$)?

I tried rewriting in terms of hyperbolic functions but it didn't help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: Let $\alpha(\mu)$ be the function $$\alpha(\mu) = \frac{e^{S\mu} - e^{-S\mu}}{e^{T\mu}-e^{-T\mu}}.$$
Try differentiating $\alpha$.

Comment: Ok, so basically I need to show that $T\coth(\mu T) \geq (T-t)\coth(\mu(T-t))$ so the derivative is negative. Do you have any idea to show this?

Comment: Try taking the derivative of $T\coth(\mu T)$ with respect to $T$.